# Angular 2 - Search pipe filter with drop down options

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a pipes that is default to name of my data set.

Next to my search field, I have a drop down with a list of options that I would like to search by.

For e.g I want to be able to search by data name, date, mission, etc. So when i click "Mission" from the drop box, any string I type in the search box will show data based should be based on mission.

Here are some snippets of code that can be helpful :

```
//search-pipe
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: any, search_term: any): any {
      if (search_term === undefined) return data;

      else {
        return data.filter(function (data){
              return data.mission.toLowerCase().includes(search_term.toLowerCase());
        })
      }
  }


//where I apply the filter

<tbody *ngFor="let test of abtest | searchPipe:search_term">...</tbody>

//search box with drop down

<form>
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
    <div class="mdl-select mdl-js-select">
      <select class="mdl-select__input"
              id="option"
              name="option"
              #select
        <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{‌{option}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
      <i class="mdl-textfield__icon material-icons">search</i>
      <input id="tf1"
             type="text"
             class="mdl-textfield__input mdl-shadow--2dp"
             #input
             (input) = "update.emit(input.value)"
             (keyup)="0" />
      <label for="tf1" class="mdl-textfield__label">Search</label>
  </div>
</form>

//app.html
<app-search (update)="search_term =$event"></app-search>
<app-show-data [search_term]="search_term"></app-show-data>
```

Comment: Use your `searchPipe` for options ? I don't get what you are missing.

Comment: I want to search by Name, Date, Owner etc. So these options are in a dropbox